# Esper Callback on Error

Tags: java, esper

I am currently using Esper within a Storm topology and I am aware that there is a method callback called `update()` that is called when Esper produces a result.

I have been wondering what would happen if there is an error within the Esper engine itself.

Is there an error callback that I can override and catch the `Exception`?

Or is my best bet to simply wrap the `sendEvent()` call in a `try-catch` and then deal with the `Exception` accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

After further reading I can see that Esper has the notion of Exception Handling:

http://esper.codehaus.org/esper-4.2.0/doc/reference/en/html/configuration.html#config-engine-exceptionhandling

This should satisfy my use case and catch any internal Esper exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Esper provides a way for [Exception Handling](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.1.0/esper-reference/html/api.html#api-exception).

You may register one or more exception handlers for the engine to invoke in the case it encounters an exception processing a continuously-executing statement

You can register ExceptionHandlerFactory like below.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.getEngineDefaults().getExceptionHandling().addClass(MyCEPEngineExceptionHandlerFactory.class);
```

You should give the full-qualified class name of each class that implements the `com.espertech.esper.client.hook.ExceptionHandlerFactory` interface in the engine defaults configuration.

For more details, please read the [documentation](http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.1.0/esper-reference/html/configuration.html#config-engine-exceptionhandling).
.